# Static content should not require session state

Tags: asp.net, session-state

In my application I dont want session state to be required for the static contents like images, javascript files and css files. To prevent this I have used

```
<Localization path="folder_containing_files">
  <system.web>
      <pages enableSessionState="false"/>
  </system.web>
</Localization>
```

Though I have used the attribute as false, session state is being called(request is being created) for static contents.

Comment: I think that images, .js- or css files are served by the asp.net runtime and since they are not served by the asp.net runtime no session will be used if you just request one of those. To find out and be sure: Stop your website, put a breakpoint in the global.asax.cs file, restart iss, start the site using debugging in visual studio and make sure that the first page you request is a static one. I don't think your breakpoint will be hit until you request an aspx page.

Comment: @mortb: I hope you mean images, .js- or css files are not  served by the asp.net runtime.

Comment: @paritosh: Yes I missed the *not* so I mean *are not served*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks you all for your support.

The only thing that was creating the request was

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

I removed the attribute runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests which means I set the value to false and the problem is resolved.
Cheers :)

Comment: runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" will force all requests to be handled by managed modules. So, in my case also, request was being created for static contents. Setting the attribute also degrades the preformance as well. So, it is a best option to set it to false and run specific modules using precondition attribute.

Answer (score 1):

first of all only registered extension in IIS  got processed through their handlers. Images , text file, css are not even processed by .net runtime. they are served by IIS.

what you are trying to achieve here by doing so?

Comment: but remember: you may configure IIS to serve them through a handler. You may also for example write a custom handler to serve images. But that is not the default case (at least wasn't in earlier versions of .net)

Comment: Thanks all. I also agree with this but the attribute above was forcefully creating request.